# Android Firebase realtime дублирование значений при запросе

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-database

при добавления новой записи в БД, предыдущие записи (которые уже есть в БД) отображаются снова в месте с новой записью, при этом в самой базе этих значений повторно нет, подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(0) {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private lateinit var workoutList: ArrayList<Workout>
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mRecyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    //TODO update total number

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupBottomNavigation()

        workoutList = arrayListOf()
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        //show total number
        showTotalNumber()
        //show daily workout on recyclerView
        showDailyWorkouts()

        //save new daily workout
        btn_apply.setOnClickListener {
            val inputData = input_approaches.text.toString().trim()
            saveApproache(inputData)
            input_approaches.setText("")
        }
    }

    private fun showTotalNumber() {
        mDatabase.child("approaches").child("number")
            .addValueEventListener(ValueEventListenerAdapter {
                val value = it.getValue()
                common_count.setText(value.toString())
            })
    }

    private fun showDailyWorkouts() {
        mDatabase.child("workouts")
            .addValueEventListener(ValueEventListenerAdapter {
                for (noteDataSnapshot in it.children) {
                    val result = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Workout::class.java)
                    workoutList.add(Workout(result!!.numberApproaches, result.dateText))
                }
                mRecyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(workoutList)
                recyclerView.adapter = mRecyclerAdapter
            })
    }

    private fun saveApproache(count: String) {
        val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        val workoutId = mDatabase.push().key

        if (count.isNotEmpty()) {
            val date = currentDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
            val approache = Workout(count, date)

            mDatabase.child("workouts").child(workoutId!!).setValue(approache)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        showToast("Данные добавлены")
                    } else {
                        showToast("Ошибка добавления данных")
                    }
                }
        } else {
            showToast("Введите количество подтягиваний")
        }
    }
}
```

```
class RecyclerAdapter(
    private val workoutList: ArrayList<Workout>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val workout: Workout = workoutList[position]
        holder.numberApproaches.text = workout.numberApproaches
        holder.dateText.text = workout.dateText
    }

    class ViewHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        var numberApproaches: TextView = item.findViewById(R.id.number_approaches)
        var dateText: TextView = item.findViewById(R.id.date_text)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return workoutList.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед этим циклом

```
for (noteDataSnapshot in it.children) {
     val result = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Workout::class.java)
     workoutList.add(Workout(result!!.numberApproaches, result.dateText))
}
```

Очисть список `workoutList` или создай новый.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
workoutList.clear();
for (noteDataSnapshot in it.children) {
    val result = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Workout::class.java)
workoutList.add(Workout(result!!.numberApproaches, result.dateText))
}
```